# $Df(x)(u) = 0$ for all $x$ and $u$ implies that $f$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f: \Bbb{R}^n \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable function.

Let $Df(x)$ denote the derivative of $f$ at $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$

I am trying to show that $Df(x)(u) = 0$ for all $u \in \Bbb{R}^n$ and all $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$ if and only if $f$ is constant.

I know that $Df$ for such kind of functions is given by the Jacobian matrix.

If $f$ is constant then it is pretty much clear that the Jacobian matrix will be the zero matrix and hence $Df(x)$ will be zero matrix for each $x$ and hence $Df(x)(u)$ will be $0$ vector.

How to show the other side?

Comment: At first you should consider the case $ f: \Bbb{R}^n \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ and then, given $ a,b\in\Bbb{R}^n$, the function $g=g_{a,b}\colon\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ with $g(t):=f((1-t)a+tb)$. Then $g'=0$, so $ g$ is constant ( and $g(a)=g(b)$).

Comment: $Df$ is not a Jacobian matrix, is a different kind of function. What is given by the Jacobian matrix is the derivative at a point, that is, $Df(x)$, for some $x$,, can be represented by a matrix